# copy/paste from Linux/TigerVNC in macOS via Screen Sharing/Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, macos, copy-paste, vnc-server

I have an Oracle Linux 8.5 desktop to which I am connecting via (Apple) Remote Desktop. On the Linux OS I am running TigerVNC server and Gnome WM. Copy/Paste between the two OSes doesn't work. I have configured the following in ~/.vnc/xstartup on the Linux server:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#added for copy/paste support
vncconfig -nowin &
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
# Assume either Gnome will be started by default when installed
# We want to kill the session automatically in this case when user logs out. In case you modify
# /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients or ~/.Xclients yourself to achieve a different result, then you should
# be responsible to modify below code to avoid that your session will be automatically killed
if [ -e /usr/bin/gnome-session ]; then
    vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
fi
```

It seems I need something like autocutsel to keep the X clipboard and the cutbuffer in sync. However autocutsel is not available for OL 8.x and I tried compiling but I got some errors.

Are there any other solutions to keep these buffers in sync?